# Is $(\mathbb{Z} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\},\leq)$ a complete lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

I read that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a complete lattice because it has no greatest lower bound (and lub).

If we define $-\infty$, $\infty$ to be integers, i.e., include them in $\mathbb{Z}$, does $\mathbb{Z}$ become a complete lattice?

If yes, then does it seem absurd to not call $\mathbb{Z}$ a complete lattice just because of something as arbitrary as inclusion of infinities in the set of integers, which is a matter of opinion?

Comment: Yes. It becomes a complete lattice since every bounded below (above) subset has a minimum (maximum).

Comment: A lattice with a least and greatest element is called a bounded lattice. Any unbounded lattice can be made into a bounded lattice by adjoining a top and bottom element to complete it (sometimes called $\top$ and $\bot$ instead of $\pm\infty$). If you think that makes the distinction between bounded lattices and lattices "absurd", ok, but they're all absurd then. Not just $\mathbb{Z}$. Anyway it's standard language. You asked about complete, not bounded, but for $\mathbb{Z}$ bounded implies complete. On the other hand, adding $\pm\infty$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ gives you bounded but not complete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $(\mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\},\leq)$ is a complete lattice, as given $S\subset \mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, either $S$ is bounded above, in which case the greatest integer in $S$ is the supremum, or its supremum is $\infty$, and likewise either $S$ is bounded below, in which case the least integer in $S$ is the infimum, or its infimum is $-\infty$.

What *complete* means is not really a matter of opinion.  A lattice $(L,\leq)$ is *complete* exactly when *every* subset of $L$ has a supremum and infimum, and since $L$ and $\emptyset$ are perfectly good subsets of $L$, we know that their supremum and infimum must exist, and this provides the minimum and maximum of $L$.

To perhaps capture what you want, however, is the idea of *Dedekind completeness*.  I.e. a lattice $(L,\leq)$ is said to be Dedekind complete exactly when every non-empty subset $S$ of $L$ which has an upper bound (i.e. bounded above) has a least upper bound.  By adding a maximum and minimum to a Dedekind complete lattice, you can make a complete lattice (though the reverse does not hold; you can't in general take a complete lattice and remove its minimum and maximum and have a Dedekind complete lattice).

This is in contrast to a *bounded-complete lattice*, in which the above non-emptiness condition is not included (and so $\emptyset$ has a supremum, which is necessarily a minimum).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is Dedekind the same as 'conditiional completeness' described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29#Conditional_completeness?

Comment: @user246228 Yep, precisely the same.